# Variadic template class, getting index of a specific type from its argument list

Tags: c++, class, variadic-templates

Would it be possible to implement a function member of a variadic template class that return the index of a given type from the variadic argument list.

The issue I see is to create some kind of fake variadic argument list, just to trigger the compile time template evaluation.

```
template<typename... TArgs>
class Foo
{
  template<typename T, typename TArg>
  int _get_idx(int i, const TArg &curr, TArgs...args)
  {
    if (std::is_same(T, TArg)) {
        return i;
    }
    else {
        return get_id(i+1, args...);
    }
  }
```

Usage would be something like:

```
Foo<A, B, C> foo;
int i = foo.get_idx<B>(); // i == 1
```

Comment: I believe [std::tuple_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tuple_element/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Nard That's the other way around, to get a type from an index. The OP wants to get an index from a type.

Comment: @T.C. From what I see, OP is using recursion to check the type of every index until he gets the right one. I believe that by using `std::tuple_element` he can do so in one loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use something like:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts> struct get_index;

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct get_index<T, T, Ts...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> {};

template <typename T, typename Tail, typename... Ts>
struct get_index<T, Tail, Ts...> :
    std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1 + get_index<T, Ts...>::value> {};

#if 1 // explicit error case, but you already have error without that. 
template <typename T>
struct get_index<T>
{
    // condition is always false, but should be dependant of T
    static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "element not found");
};
#endif
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/Zn0eQf)

Note: You don't specify what happens for duplicate matching type (So I take the first one),
nor if the type is not matched (so I did a compile time error)

[Live Demo with duplicates](https://ideone.com/gwSaaH)

Comment: There are better ways to do the "type not found" case. Right now it's ill-formed no diagnostic required, so a hypothetical future compiler could reject it.

Comment: @T.C: I have added the explicit "type not found" case to allow OP to have other behaviour (as returning `-1`). Comment added.

Comment: @Jarod42: Thanks, works like a charm! The "type not found" case should not compile, as in your code. About duplicated types, it should not compile too, but since this seems difficult to achieve (I think), this can be left as unspecified.

Comment: @Stringer: You may add something like `static_assert(!contains<T, Ts...>::value, "duplicate element found");` (with a `contains` similar to `get_index`) in `get_index<T, T, Ts...>`.

Comment: @Jarod42: Could you explain as detect duplicates? I'm lost and I don't understand it.